# Interactive command in command substitution bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a shell script that asks for a value and depending on the valued entered returns a value. Imagine that it's called "reve" and contains something like

```
read fname
rev << EOF 
$fname
EOF
```

Then if I have a file that is called "file.txt" and I do

```
vi `./reve`
```

Then waits for user input. If I type "txt.elif" vi opens "file.txt". Correct until now. But the problem is when the script is something like the following

```
echo "Enter inverted file name"
read fname
rev << EOF 
$fname
EOF
```

Then it tries to open a file called "Enter inverted file name".

Is it possible to ask for the value with the text and after that use the returned value only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need it to be interactive, then you could print the message on ***stderr*** instead.

```
echo "Enter inverted file name" > /dev/stderr
read fname
rev << EOF 
$fname
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using a really old shell, `read` should have a `-p` option to supply a prompt.  It automatically sends the prompt to stderr instead of stdout, and skips the linefeed (so the response is on the same line as the prompt):

```
read -p "Enter inverted file name: " fname
rev << EOF 
$fname
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Force writing to, and reading from, the terminal using `/dev/tty`.

In your example this will be:

```
echo -e "Enter inverted file name: \c" > /dev/tty
read fname < /dev/tty
rev << EOF 
$fname
EOF
```

I used `echo -e ... \c` so no newline is printed and your input is entered on the same line.